# Import database from mysql in orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to import a database having only one table into orientdb using their import functionality. I wrote this json

```
`{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
              "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/footballEvents",
              "userName": "root",
              "userPassword": "root",
              "query": "select * from 10eventslight_2" }
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "events"} }
  ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "remote:localhost/footballEvents",
      "dbUser": "root",
      "dbPassword": "root",
      "serverUser": "root",
      "serverPassword": "root",
      "dbAutoCreate": true
    }
  }
}`
```

Then I run the command `sudo ./oetl.sh importScript.json` and I don't get any error, the script runs normally. I attached the output of the command [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPOe5.jpg)

Reading the `[orientdb] INFO committing` message at the end I tried to connect to my database and run the `commit` command but the system answers me that no transaction is running. I'm quite sure that the dbUrl and the db/server credentials in my json are good because I can use this address to connect to my database via the orientdb console. Concerning the mysql part, no doubt it's working because it extracts data from the database and I know my credentials are ok.

So it looks like it's working, not any error comes up but nothing happens and I don't understand why.

If it has any importance, I'm on Mac OS 10.13.1 with orientdb 2.2.29.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: commit doesn't work because the transaction was already committed, did you try querying the database for any of those imported data?

Comment: Yes I tried querying the database and I didn’t have any answer, the database is empty. I tried both with the CLI and with the GUI

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB Teleporter is a tool that synchronizes a RDBMS to OrientDB database. Teleporter is fully compatible with several RDBMS that have a JDBC driver: Teleporter has been successfully tested with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HyperSQL. Teleporter manages all the necessary type conversions between the different DBMSs and imports all your data as Graph in OrientDB. This feature is available both for the OrientDB Enterprise Edition and the OrientDB Community Edition. But beware: in community edition you can migrate your source relational database but you cannot enjoy the synchronize feature, only available in the enterprise edition.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Teleporter-Home.html

Hope it helps

Regards